# CRM 2011, Solution and publisher options not available

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

The problem is that when i go to Settings -> Customizations,
it does not allow me to make any changes to existing entites,
neither it allows me to create a new, custom one.

It just displays a simple message: 
WARNING: Solution and Publisher Options are not available since your language does not match system base language.

I tried googleing and searching for an option to find this base system language, thus far no succes.
How can i achieve the possibility to edit and create new custom entities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**How:** Change the current language to the base language and try again.

**Why:** You are only allowed to make customization to the system if the **current language** set is in fact the same as the **base language** set during the installation.

**IMHO:** I've asked around a while ago why it's that way but I didn't get any straight and acceptable answer. It was more of "*it just is like that*" and "*you can handle it this and that way*". So, until provided a better explanation, I claim cockily that it's just an unnecessarily inconvenient design. :)

Comment: about the dumb answers that you sometimes get from MS, i totally agree.

Comment: and thanks for the answer, will come back after trying to change it.

Comment: @Freeman Sure! And if/when it works - don't forget to check a reply as an answer. Otherwise, explain what's wrong still.

Comment: i might have forgot that its the online verion of CRM so changing the base language is greyed out.

Comment: I quote you "You are only allowed to make customization to the system if the current language set is in fact the same as the base language set during the installation." So of course i colud not change the base language, but i used the same language as the base one, and now i am good to go, thank you...

Answer (score 3):

Check this [article](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/pabloperalta/archive/2011/03/27/how-to-change-the-language-in-dynamics-crm-2011.aspx) that demonstrate how change base and user language, and have the next warning:

> **Bear in mind that as administrators / customizers if we need to customize any entity and/or solution, this can only be done if the logged user is using the base language (english in this case).**

Comment: thanks for the article, its straight forward, will try tommorow to see if it works.

Comment: i might have forgot that its the online verion of CRM so changing the base language is greyed out.

Comment: It's right you can't change, but you can change your base language. Do it temporally.

Comment: For the online version of the CRM 2011, you can set the base language only once at subscribtion time. After that moment you must email them to change the base lang again. Just another day in the dumb idea world...